# AccordionPanel doesn't render the last tab

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm developing with JSF & Primefaces and using the accordionPanel component in one of my current projects. This is a snippet code regarding to how I'm using it:

```
<p:accordionPanel id="historic" dynamic="true" 
                  styleClass="noborder" 
                  activeIndex="-1">

    <p:tab id="tab1" title="Historic 1" >
            <ui:include src="historic1.xhtml"/>
    </p:tab>

    <p:tab id="tab2" title="Historic 2">
            <ui:include src="historic2.xhtml"/>
    </p:tab>

    <p:tab id="tab3" title="Historic 3">
            <ui:include src="historic3.xhtml"/>
    </p:tab>

    <p:tab id="tab4" title="Historic 4">
            <ui:include src="historic4.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>

</p:accordionPanel>
```

All the tabs contain basically the same code, a form with some data pointing to different datasets. As you guys can see, it's pretty simple and works properly except with the last tab. It's never shown, whatever it contains. I mean, if, instead the code above, I put this other:

```
<p:accordionPanel id="historic" dynamic="true" 
                  styleClass="noborder" 
                  activeIndex="-1">
    <p:tab id="tab1" title="Historic 1" >
            <ui:include src="historic1.xhtml"/>
    </p:tab>

    <p:tab id="tab2" title="Historic 2">
            <ui:include src="historic2.xhtml"/>
    </p:tab>

    <p:tab id="tab3" title="Historic 3">
            <ui:include src="historic3.xhtml"/>
    </p:tab>

    <p:tab id="tab4" title="Historic 4">
            <ui:include src="historic4.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>

    <p:tab id="tab5" title="Historic 5">
           Some plain test text.
    </p:tab>

</p:accordionPanel>
```

then the tab4 is now shown, but the tab5 isn't. I'm currently using this last code, but it's a bit ugly, because of the empty tab.
Has any of you faced the same or similar problem and can help me? I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accordionPanel index is a zero-based one. This is, 0 for the first tab, 1 for the second one, and so on. That is why
 a tried to use "-1" as an index, because I didn't want any tab to be opened by default.
But this value (-1) produces a malfunction in the accordionPanel: the last tab does not open properly. So if -1 doesn't work and 0 is the value for the first tab, what about a value "over" the last one. I mean, if we have 4 tabs (indexes from 0 to 3), let's try with 4... and it works. So simple. I hope this can be helpful for anyone who find themselves in the same problem.
Anyway, thank @Aksel Willgert, you gave me the clue.

Answer (score 2):

From the primefaces vdl: http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/accordionPanel.html

activeIndex

> Index of the active tab or a comma separated string of indexes when
>   multiple mode is on. Default is zero.

There might be reasons you set this to -1, the example you provided works in primefaces 3.4.2 if you set it to 0 or a positive number

Comment: It works. Thank you a lot. I simply thought that accordionPanel index was a zero-based system. I mean, zero for the first tab and so on. It was a mistake. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm sorry saying this, but eventually it didn't work.  I don't know why it did it the time I tried, may be because of the cache, but I've just run the application again and it failed. Anyway, I've found out the solution, which I'm writing below as an answer to my own question.